# Teradata -execute "SHOW SELECT FROM" in a stored procedure or etl alternative

Tags: sql, teradata

I am trying to do a call to Teradata with a list of views of which I want to know the tables.
So I built a loop in an etl tool to execute "SHOW QUALIFIED SELECT * FROM ..." on all of them.
However, this seems to be unsupported and the teradata documentation suggests this too (any form of SHOW is not supported in stored procedures).

Could you think of another way to get the underlying tables in a view?

thank you

- Update: FYI SHOW SELECT * FROM ... is different from SHOW VIEW
  in that it also shows -ALL- underlying tables involved, e.g. in case of views on views.

Comment: Build your `SHOW VIEW ...;` statements in Excel or whatever. Paste them all into SQL Assistant.  You can run it there, but all the results will be in individual tabs. If you want them in a single file, under Tools > Options > Export, select write  to a single file. Then under File, select Export results.  No easy way, sadly enough.

Comment: You could also use `bteq` to run your `SHOW VIEW` statements and capture the output to a file.

Comment: i did so by building an ETL solution that joined view definitions from dbc.tablesv and just iterated through them. Was a bit of work but it got the results - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Alternate call for the SHOW VIEW:

```
select createText from dbc.tvm t1 join dbc.dbase t2 on (t1.databaseId=t2.databaseId)
where TVMName = '<your_view_name>'
  and databaseNameI = '<your_db_name>'
;
```

Comment: this is about show select * from, not show view.. thank you